# Using enums in react const

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, enums, constants, react-props

I need to map `enum` values to 1 variable and then call the variable and check if that enum was present or not.

```
render() {
    const {
        id,
        name,
        features} = this.props;
}
```

Features would be the variable that needs to be mapped according to which enums are coming in. I would get something similar from the API:

```
{"id":"111", "name":"jack", "features":["MOUNTAIN", "HILL"]}
```

So there would be a total of 4 different `features` : `MOUNTAIN, HILL, LAKE, FISH`. 

Then when needed I can check:

```
if(features.mountain)
    //do stuff
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like to check if a given property from your enum (for example "MOUNTAIN") is included in the features array returned from the api you can use the [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method:

```js
if(featuresArrayfromApi.includes('MOUNTAIN'){
   //do stuff
}
```

If you would like to check if the features returned from the api include one or more of the properties in your features enum you can combine `includes` with [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

For example, in Typescript you would write it like this:

```js
enum Features { MOUNTAIN, HILL, LAKE, FISH }

if(Object.keys(Features)
 .some(feature => featuresFromApi.includes(feature))){
   // do stuff
}
```

**Edit**

The `features` key from the api data should be mapped like any other key(`id`, `name`) - just instead of holding 1 value it holds an array. Then you can use the validations suggested above in an `if` clause. For example:

```
const data = [
    {"id":"111", "name":"jack", "features":["MOUNTAIN", "HILL"]},
    {"id":"222", "name":"john", "features":["FISH", "HILL", "LAKE"]}
    {"id":"333", "name":"joe", "features":["LAKE", "HILL", "FISH"]}

    ]

    data.map(record =>{

      console.log(record.id); 
      console.log(record.name);

      if (record.features.includes('MOUNTAIN'){
          // do stuff
        }          
    })
```

Also, bear in mind that `enum` is a Typescript symbol which isn't available in Javascript, so in case you are not using Typescript you can just declare it like this and it would work the same:

```
const Features =  { 
 MOUNTAIN: "MOUNTAIN",
 HILL: "HILL",
 LAKE, "LAKE",
 FISH: "FISH" 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how would you map this enum to a const variable? Or will it be mapped by itself when `Features` are declared? The other variables in this example.. id, name are being mapped.

Comment: If I understand the question, the `features` key from the api data should be mapped like any other key, it just holds any array instead of a single value. Please look at the "Edit" I've added to the question - does this answer your question?